# error getting eslint to work with eslint-plugin-vue

Tags: javascript, npm, eslint

I'm not a front-end dev but am trying to lint my javascript / Vue.js file in a Rails 5.1 app. I'm not that familiar with the node ecosystem.  I get the following error and wanted to know where to start to fix this:

```text
Tue Apr 17$ eslint javascript/ --ext .vue
Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-vue'
Referenced from: /Users/jt/repos/embers2/.eslintrc.js
Error: Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-vue'
Referenced from: /Users/jt/repos/embers2/.eslintrc.js
    at ModuleResolver.resolve (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb-standard/node_modules/eslint/lib/util/module-resolver.js:74:19)
    at resolve (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb-standard/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:466:29)
    at load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb-standard/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:542:26)
    at configExtends.reduceRight (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb-standard/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:421:36)
    at Array.reduceRight (<anonymous>)
    at applyExtends (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb-standard/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:403:28)
    at loadFromDisk (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb-standard/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:514:22)
    at Object.load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb-standard/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:550:20)
    at Config.getLocalConfigHierarchy (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb-standard/node_modules/eslint/lib/config.js:228:44)
    at Config.getConfigHierarchy (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb-standard/node_modules/eslint/lib/config.js:180:43)
Tue Apr 17$
```

My .eslint.js file is:

```js
module.exports = {
  extends: [
    // add more generic rulesets here, such as:
    // 'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:vue/essential',
    'airbnb-base'

  ],
  rules: {
    // override/add rules settings here, such as:
    // 'vue/no-unused-vars': 'error'
  }
};
```

and my package.json is:

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/webpacker": "^3.4.3",
    "axios": "^0.17.1",
    "coffeescript": "1.12.7",
    "octicons": "^6.0.1",
    "postcss-smart-import": "^0.7.6",
    "solc": "^0.4.19",
    "vue": "^2.5.16",
    "vue-awesome": "^2.3.4",
    "vue-cookie": "^1.1.4",
    "vue-loader": "^14.2.2",
    "vue-moment": "^3.2.0",
    "vue-octicon": "^2.1.1",
    "vue-progressbar": "^0.7.3",
    "vue-router": "^2.7.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.16",
    "vue2-google-maps": "^0.8.10",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^12.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^4.4.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "vue-masonry-css": "^1.0.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.13",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.11.1"
  }
}
```

Where do I start looking to debug this? This ecosystem is still very opaque to me.

---

On a comment's request, I ran `npm install` and verified that the plugin appears to be in `./node_modules/`:

[image: "eslint-plugin-vue" is in the node_modules folder]

But I'm still getting the same error. Any other ideas?

Comment: Wherever your package.json file is, try dong `npm install` in the terminal/cmd. The npm package `eslint-plugin-vue` is not installed and this command will install all packages in package.json and overwrite those that exist already.

Comment: thx @RahulDesai - I did that and am getting the same error. the plugin appears to be in my ./node_modules/ . Any other ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the eslint working directories in `.vscode/settings.json` as following

```
{
  "eslint.workingDirectories": [
    "./client",
  ]
}
```

Here, `./client` path is relative to where you initiated your visual studio code i.e. where your project root is

[image]

Comment: Man... any idea why this doesn't simply work for all directories out of the box?